# $T:\ L^2(0,1)\rightarrow L^1(0,1)$ find operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis

$$T:\ L^2(0,1)\rightarrow L^1(0,1)$$
$$Tf(t)=f(t^{3/2})$$

How do I find (and prove) the norm of this operator?

My solution is a bit intuitive and not rigorous at all:

I know, that $||T||=\sup_{||f||=1}||Tf||$. So I take a set of functions, that are in $L^2$ and normalize them all to 1. That is:
$$\{(2\alpha+1)\frac{1}{x^\alpha}\ |\ \alpha\in(0,\frac{1}{2}) \}$$

I take this set, because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ does not lie in $L_2$ so I suppose, that
$$||T(\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}})||_1=8$$
is the norm I'm looking for. But I'm not sure how to prove this rigorously

Comment: If you're normalising, the constant in front needs to be $\sqrt{1-2\alpha}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, $\vert\vert Tf\vert\vert=\int_0^1f(t^{3/2})dt=\int_0^1f(u)(\frac{2}{3u^{1/3}})du$. To find the norm, we turn to the variational problem:

Maximise $I[f]={\int_0^1f(x)(\frac{2}{3x^{1/3}})dx}$ given that $J[f]=\int_0^1f(x)^2dx=1$

Calculus of Variations crossed with Lagrange multipliers gives us that we must solve $\delta I[f]-\lambda J[f]=0, J[f]=1$. This leads us to $\frac{2}{3x^{1/3}}-\lambda (2f)=0$, i.e. that our extremal solution will be a multiple of $x^{-1/3}$.

Routine verification gives that we must have $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}x^{-1/3}$, which gives $\vert\vert Tf \vert\vert=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$. Comparison with $f(x)=1$ confirms that this is a maximum, and we obtain $\vert\vert T\vert\vert=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$

Note also that we can alternatively use Cauchy-Schwarz to jump straight to the solution, as $\vert\vert Tf \vert\vert = \langle f,\frac{2}{3u^{1/3}}\rangle\leq\vert\vert f\vert\vert_{L^2}\vert\vert\frac{2}{3u^{1/3}}\vert\vert_{L^2}$

---

[This solution is for if the codomain is also $L^2(0,1)$, based on an initial misreading of the question]

$\vert\vert Tf\vert\vert^2=\int_0^1f(t^{3/2})^2dt=\int_0^1f(u)^2(\frac{2}{3u^{1/3}})du=\int_0^1(f(u)\frac{\sqrt6}{3u^{1/6}})^2du$, so $T$ has the same norm as a multiplication operator. (Above, we make the substitution $t^{3/2}=u,dt=\frac{2du}{u^{1/3}}$)

Cauchy-Schwartz gives us that $\vert\vert Tf\vert\vert^2\leq\vert\vert f\vert\vert^2\vert\vert g\vert\vert^2$, where $g(x)=\frac{\sqrt6}{3x^{1/6}}$, and also gives us a direct route to finding that this bound is achieved (when $f=g$).

We note finally that $\vert\vert g\vert\vert^2=\int_0^1(\frac{2}{3x^{1/3}})dx=[x^{2/3}]_0^1=1$, so the operator norm of $T$ is $1$.

Interestingly, this proof gives us another result basically for free: If $h(x)$ is a $C^1$-bijection from $[0,1]$ to itself, then the operator $C_hf(x)=f(h(x))$ will have norm equal to $1$. I suspect that the $C^1$ constraint may not even be necessary - the mapping is basically a [permutation/automorphism] of $[0,1]$, and on finite-dimensional vector spaces, such transformations readily have norm 1. Does make the calculus cleaner to add the $C^1$ constraint anyhow.

Comment: Shouldn't you be computing the $L^1$ norm of $Tf$?

Comment: Ah - my mistake, hadn't noticed that. Will re-assess. Thanks.

Comment: Tf(t) = f(t^{3/2}), not f(t^{2/3}), yes?

Comment: Yep, typo - the rest ought to be true still (substitution is $t^{3/2}=u$, which I'll add in).

Comment: Thank you, I'm afraid the variation solution is a bit of an overkill. I wanted to suggest to use Hölder inequality, but I see you've already done so in the edit.

Comment: Yeah, I was considering Hölder the first time around but got thrown by the mix of norms it might have involved. Turned out to be exactly the right tool, which in retrospect is perhaps what I should have expected. Agree that the variational method is a bit much - mostly I was just fairly sure that it'd point me in the right direction, if nothing else.